# How to add_js per content type in my module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking for a way for my module to evaluate the content type in a preprocess hook and conditionally add some javascript.

*Theme*_preprocess_page() makes the content type accessible plus some other useful things (I could differentiate between nodes & views & such), but I can't use it because it is likely to have already been declared by the theme.

*My_module*_preprocess_page() doesn't appear to provide the content type anywhere.

What is a good option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to add content type specific javascript to a node using [`hook_node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and `#attached`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  // Add content type specific JS on full page node view
  if($view_mode == 'full'){
    switch($node->type){
      case 'article':
        $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array('data' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/js/article.js');
      break;
      case 'page':
        $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array('data' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/js/page.js');    
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: cool.  I'm not familiar w/ `hook_node_view`; I'll look it up tomorrow.